# Fragment not loading when clicked from avigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, androiddesignsupport

Hi I used android studio wizard to create a drawer activity. Inside MainnActivity I have put this code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_movies) {
            Fragment newDetail = ListFragment.newInstance(LAUNCH_MOVIES);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, newDetail)
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tv) {
            Fragment newDetail = ListFragment.newInstance(LAUNCH_TV);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, newDetail)
                    .commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Since I have 2 options I need to launch the same fragment with different arguments, and based on the different arguments the fragment shows different things. But when I click on a navigation drawer item nothing appears on screen nor on the stacktrace.

ListFragment:

```
public static ListFragment newInstance(int target) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SCOPE, target);
        ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ListFragment() {
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scope = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SCOPE);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        switch (scope){
            case 1:
                //launch Movies
                ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("" + MainActivity.LAUNCH_MOVIES);
                break;
            case 2:
                //Launch tv
                ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("" + MainActivity.LAUNCH_TV);
                break;
            default:
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "INVALID SCOPE");
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

Thank you I am going crazy.

XML files:
**activity_main**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    ...>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        .../>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ...>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            .../>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/container"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would really love to know why my question has been downvoted and no resolutive answers have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Debuger? You can see code flow using break-points.

Comment: I tried logging everything and I've haven't had much luck with the debugger. Where do you suggest placing the breakpoints?

Comment: First you can try putting on `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method in order to see it those methods are calling (in first line of code, not mehod), then using `F9` you can go automatically on next executed line. Usualy put break-points where you expected code need to be called. Edit: did you inflate meniu in order to listen to click events?

Comment: What do you mean about inflation? I created a drawer activity through Android Studio so I guess everything has been taken care of.

Comment: In this case, it should take care.. Please update your question with MainActivity code.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you used the Android Studio debugger stepping through line by line you will likely find your problem. Everything seems fine to me but I can't see all the code or XML.
What does MainActivity.LAUNCH_TV and MainActivity.LAUNCH_MOVIES return? They may be returning nothing and leaving you with an empty text view and therefore it may seem like the buttons are not working.
Another problem could be that R.id.nav_movies and R.id.nav_tv are not right but I can't tell as all your XML is not included. 
Set the debugger to break on the first line of onNavigationItemSelected and just step one line at a time, the problem should become easier to solve once you know where it is.

Comment: MainActivity.LAUNCH_TV and _MOVIES are two integer constants. One is = 1 and the other = 2. The default case for the switch should give a warning log, but it doesn't happen, so either the switch case is not being called or the whole fragment is not being created.  R.id.nav_movies and _tv are fine otherwise I would get a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `navigationView` `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` is not being called. Have you set the listener to your `navigationView`?

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

Comment: As I said the activity was created anew through AS, and infact this exact line is present in MainActivity#onCreate. `NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your approach.The problem you are facing is replace fragment id.You should use Relativelayout id from content_main.xml file, while replacing the fragment

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
```

Also remove Framelayout from app_bar_main.xml file.

Comment: This gets closer to the solution: if i put the <include=content_main.xml> instead of the frame layout, and do the rest of what you said it works. But then I am both placing the frag in content_main.xml both I am inflating it with the Inflater. If I try to load another xml file in onCreateView I see again a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working. Apparenly it was some bug in the way the xml files are organized. The java code was left as it was. Instead in `app_bar_main`, inside the coordinator layout I put a FrameLayout with id `@+id/fragment_container`. Also I removed the self-generated `<Include content_main.xml>` tag.

In the onNavigationItemSelected method I updated every .replace() to target the new FrameLayout like this: `.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newDetail)`.

Then in the fragment's onCreateView i inflated a new layout like this: `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);`, where fragment_list is the layout where I have the recycerView and all of the UI stuff.

The `content_main.xml` went unused.

I believe the bug was somehow related to the `<include>` tag and the messy over-complicated way of adding a Drawer. 2/10 never using Drawer again.